# How do I create objects with a different number of arguments?

Tags: java

my question is what if I want to create an object that represents a person in a contact list.
The user has to enter a last name, if not, the program won't work.
Besides that the user can enter the first name, the address, phone number and so on, but these aren't necessary.
So how do I tackle these?
I could create a huge amount of constructors with the different parameter combinations, but I don't think that is the right solution.

Can you guys help me out?

Comment: I would place the mandatory values in the constructor and set the optional ones using setters.

Answer (score 3):

Simple way : using a constructor with mandatory fields and provides setters to value the other fields.

More complex way if immutability is required: using a builder to build the Person instance.

`Builder` should be a static nested class of `Person` that provides a way to build a `Builder` object and the `Builder` class provides method to set values of the `Builder` object.
Each one of this method returns the current `Builder` instance but `build()` that creates and returns the created `Person` object.

Here is a sample class :

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phone;

    // private constructor
    private Person() {
    }

    public static class Builder {

      private String name;
      private String address;
      private String phone;

      // mandatory fields
      public Builder(String name) {
        this.name = name;
      }

      public Builder address(String address) {
        this.address = address;
        return this;
      }

      public Builder phone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
        return this;
      }

      public Person build() {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.name = name;
        p.address = address;
        p.phone = phone;
        return p;
      }
   }

}
```

You could use then it in this way :

```
Person person = new Person.Builder("myName").address("myAddress").build();
```

or

```
 Person person = new Person.Builder("myName").address("myAddress").phone("my phone").build();
```

Comment: How's the builder pattern related to immutability?

Comment: @beatng You don't need to provide setter for `Person` and the object is created in a single call (`build()`).

Comment: Sure, you don't have to. But "if immutability is required" sounds a bit confusing. Applying the builder pattern simply separates construction and representation; it doesn't affect the (im)mutability of the corresponding class. Nonetheless, +1 for suggesting the pattern.

Comment: @beatngu13 when you use a builder as the sole way to construct an object and do not provide setters then it is immutable. In general if there are no setters the class is immutable but since the OP requires optional fields a builder is the best if not the only way to do it.

Comment: @beatngu13 I am not sure to get your point. Applying the builder pattern provide a way to not providing setter to the built object. When we set values,  we change only the state of the `builder` instance, not which of them of the Person object that is created only when build() is invoked. I  edited my answer to give a sample code.

Comment: @JonathanRosenne If you use a plain ctor and no setters the class is immutable as well. My point is that the builder pattern and (im)mutability are generally not related to each other. However, I think we talk at cross-purposes.

Comment: @beatngu13 This is what I said, however the OP specified a number of optional fields so one may either have a number of constructors or a builder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of setters?

I once had this problem in a project and I thought of it this way:

1. The must fill values: pass them through a constructor
2. The optional values: pass them using setters

Code sample of the class person:

```
    public class person {

    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber;

    //lastName is mandatory you should pass when you create your object
    public person(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    //This is optional you can pass it using this setter
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    //This is optional you can pass it using this setter
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    //This is optional you can pass it using this setter
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    }
```

Code sample of the main class

```
public class yourclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String lastname="fooer"; //choose how you want to intercept the input if you are building a GUI app, tell me I would help you with JavaFx or Swing code.
        String firstname="foo" //let's say this is the only optional to pass
        person newperson = new person(lastname);
        if (firstname.isEmpty()==false)
            newperson.setFirstName(firstname);

    }
}
```

Comment: okay but what if someone doesn't pass a value for the setMethod? since everything besides the last name isn't necessary?

Comment: If it is necessary if someone does not fill them the app stills function the correct way right? The set method is there you use it or not no problem BUT the constructor you gotta pass it the right arguments to create the object.

Comment: do you have a sample code for me? Every time I don't pass a value in my setMethod I get an error

Comment: Done, do you want me to add more code of how you should call this in your main?

Comment: Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

What you don't want to try is [telescoping constructor pattern](http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/05/telescoping-constructor-antipattern.html#.WTQ8axOGPVo)? This is easy to implement if you have lesser no of fields(thus lesser constructor required)
In terms of good design, you can consider following:
[**Builder Design pattern**](http://www.journaldev.com/1425/builder-design-pattern-in-java)

```
public class Computer {

    //required parameters
    private String HDD;
    private String RAM;

    //optional parameters
    private boolean isGraphicsCardEnabled;
    private boolean isBluetoothEnabled;


    public String getHDD() {
        return HDD;
    }

    public String getRAM() {
        return RAM;
    }

    public boolean isGraphicsCardEnabled() {
        return isGraphicsCardEnabled;
    }

    public boolean isBluetoothEnabled() {
        return isBluetoothEnabled;
    }

    private Computer(ComputerBuilder builder) {
        this.HDD=builder.HDD;
        this.RAM=builder.RAM;
        this.isGraphicsCardEnabled=builder.isGraphicsCardEnabled;
        this.isBluetoothEnabled=builder.isBluetoothEnabled;
    }

    //Builder Class
    public static class ComputerBuilder{

        // required parameters
        private String HDD;
        private String RAM;

        // optional parameters
        private boolean isGraphicsCardEnabled;
        private boolean isBluetoothEnabled;

        public ComputerBuilder(String hdd, String ram){
            this.HDD=hdd;
            this.RAM=ram;
        }

        public ComputerBuilder setGraphicsCardEnabled(boolean isGraphicsCardEnabled) {
            this.isGraphicsCardEnabled = isGraphicsCardEnabled;
            return this;
        }

        public ComputerBuilder setBluetoothEnabled(boolean isBluetoothEnabled) {
            this.isBluetoothEnabled = isBluetoothEnabled;
            return this;
        }

        public Computer build(){
            return new Computer(this);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use different patterns:

- JavaBeans (Getters and Setters)
- Telescoping constructor (with different number of parameters)
- Builder pattern

But non of them will guarantee the user's input you're expecting.

It mostly depends on your UI, and what data may came to you from UI.

If there is possibility that UI can send you nulls, or empty String, you should handle them fro mandatory fields, because it's your business logic, no matter which pattern you're using.

Let's sare you're required to build new Person from the DTOPerson which is came from UI:

```
public Person register(Person personDTO) {
    validatePerson(personDTO);
    Person person = new Person(personDTO.getName(), personDTO.getSurname());
    // for not mandatory fields
    person.setAddress(personDTO.getAddress());

    // ...
}

public void validatePerson(Person person) {
    Optional.ofNullable(person.getName()).orElseThrow(() -> 
        new IllegalArgumentException("Name is required!")
    );

    Optional.ofNullable(person.getSurname()).orElseThrow(() ->
            new IllegalArgumentException("Surname is required!")
    );
}
```